# Find the value of $0.5^{0.5^{0.5^{0.5^\ldots}}}$

Tags: limits, logarithms, exponential-function, infinity

Find the value of $0.5^{0.5^{0.5^{0.5^\ldots}}}$

My attempt:
$$\begin{aligned}
&0.5^{0.5^{0.5^{0.5^\ldots}}} =: x \\
&\Rightarrow\ 0.5^x = x \\
&\Rightarrow\ -x \ln(2) = \ln(x) \\
&\Rightarrow\ \ln(x) = -x \ln(2) \\
&\Rightarrow x\approx0.64
\end{aligned}$$

But, by letting the value is $x$ means I am assuming that the expresstion has a real value $x$. How we can prove that more logically.

Comment: $.5^1$ is not $1$.

Comment: What computation did you do?  I set $a_1=.5$ and $a_n=.5^{a_{n-1}}$.   That gives $a_{25}=0.641185745$

Comment: Well, it shouldn't.  With my notation, $a_{10}=0.641284509$

Comment: wolfram gives x=W(log 2)/(log 2)=.641186 see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+%281%2F2%29%5Ex%3Dx

Comment: Oh, I see. You are computing the iterated square root.  $\cdots \sqrt {\sqrt {\sqrt {.5}}}$.  But that's different.  $a^{b^c}=a^{\left(b^c\right)}$, not $\left(a^b\right)^c$.  Use the recursion I proposed to do the computation, it converges very quickly.

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. Many questions about the convergence of an infinite power tower and where it converges are on this site.

Comment: By setting $\,a_1=0.5\,,\,$ $a_{n+1}=0.5^{a_n},\,$ I got the following values: $$a_1=0.5$$ $$a_2=0.707106781…$$ $$a_3=0.612547327…$$ $$a_4=0.65404086…$$ $$a_5=0.635497846…$$ $$a_6=0.643718642…$$ $$a_7=0.640061021…$$ $$a_8=0.641685807…$$ $$a_9=0.640963537…$$ $$a_{10}=0.641284509…$$ $$a_{11}=0.641141851…$$ $$a_{12}=0.641205252…$$ $$a_{13}=0.641177075…$$ $$a_{14}=0.641189598…$$ $$a_{15}=0.641184032…$$ 
$$a_{16}=0.641186506…$$ $$a_{17}=0.641185406…$$ $$a_{18}=0.641185895…$$ $$a_{19}=0.641185678…$$
$$a_{20}=0.641185774…$$ $$a_{21}=0.641185731…$$
$$a_{21}=0.64118575…$$ $$a_{22}=0.641185742…$$

Comment: $$a_{23}=0.641185746…$$ $$a_{24}=0.641185744…$$
$$a_{25}=0.641185745…$$ So I think actually there is not any contradiction.

Comment: When asking a question like this — **just in case you are hoping that anyone will understand your question** — it is necessary to state where the parentheses in you iterated-exponentiation expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The confusion is a result of the fact that iterated exponentiation is non-associative.  When one writes, e.g., $a^{b^c}$, what is meant is $a^{(b^c)}$, not $\left(a^b\right)^c$.  The latter is just $a^{bc}$, of course.

The OP was, apparently, computing the iterated square root $$\cdots \sqrt {\sqrt {\sqrt {.5}}}$$  which is indeed $1$.

However, this is not what is meant by the original iterated exponentiation.  That problem can be rewritten  as $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$ where the $a_n$ are defined recursively as $$a_1=.5\quad a_n=.5^{a_{n-1}}$$

If you use that definition you get the desired value very rapidly.

Comment: Again,  that's not how iterated exponentiation works.  By definition,  they mean the recursive limit I wrote. You are computing something else.

Comment: Non associative operations are tricky.  You have to take care to make sure your grouping is the intended one.

Comment: For instance $3^{3^3}$ is $3^{27}$,.  It is not $27^3$.